# Best practice to synchronize data using a cloud database storage regarding latency

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Writing data to a cloud database storage (Azure tables) does not ensure that you receive the latest (updated) data when you retrieve all data from the database immediately after the database update function is called.

How to deal with this latency of data in the client application? What is the best practice? Is there a generic solution to deal with the latency of data that occurs when using cloud databases such as Microsoft Azure table storage?